# convert ElasticSearch field value to lowercase and do aggregation with that field

Tags: elasticsearch

I tried to use painless script to convert the value in aggregation section. But it doesn't allow me doing that.

```json
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "term": {
            "testData": {
              "value": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggregations": {
    "FieldAggregationSpend": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "spend.keyword",
        "size": 500,
        "min_doc_count": 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
        "order": [
          {
            "_count": "desc"
          },
          {
            "_key": "asc"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "Field": {
          "terms": {
            "script": {
              "source": "def sentiment=doc['response.keyword'].toLowercase(); return sentiment;",
              "lang": "painless"
            },
            "size": 500,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
              {
                "_count": "desc"
              },
              {
                "_key": "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can make it ?

I have the following response value: "Good", "good", "gOOd". And wish to have all of them in the same aggregation bucket.

```
{
  key: good,
  doc_count: 3
}
```

Not sure if I can use analyzer, since all my data are already there in the index.

Comment: What does it mean "But it doesn't allow me doing that." ? Any error you can share?

Comment: It is a 400 error. think there is syntax error.

Comment: Maybe show the error you get, it will be easier for everyone :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found the problem for this script. In our index mapping, the field is set with type "string". I should convert "string" to "String", then it works.  the change is { def sentiment=doc['response.keyword'].value.toString().toLowercase(); return sentiment;}